# Could not resolve type id 'http' into a subtype of [simple type, class io.dropwizard.jetty.ConnectorFactory]: known type ids = [ConnectorFactory]

Tags: java, azure, gradle, yaml, dropwizard

I created a new VM Instance in AZURE and trying to deploy my java web -application(which is successfully deployed in aws server). gradle build is successful.While running the application through my classpath i am getting the following error.

**Failed to parse configuration at: server.applicationConnectors.[0]; Could not resolve type id 'http' into a subtype of [simple type, class io.dropwizard.jetty.ConnectorFactory]: known type ids = [ConnectorFactory]
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.voicemonk.config.DialogServiceConfiguration["server"]->io.dropwizard.server.DefaultServerFactory["applicationConnectors"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])**

I have tried adding shadow dependency also bot nothing is working out.

build.gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'application'
    apply plugin:'base'
    apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

    // Use Java 8 by default
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'

   // UTF-8 should be standard by now. So use it!
   [compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

   project.ext {
      dropwizardVersion = '0.8.4'
      guavaVersion = '19.0'
      httpComponentsVersion = '4.3.6'
      guiceVersion = '3.0'
   }

   mainClassName = 'com.voicemonk.service.name'


   dependencies {

      compile (
        'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:' + dropwizardVersion,
        'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-hibernate:' + dropwizardVersion,
        'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-migrations:' + dropwizardVersion,
        'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-auth:' + dropwizardVersion,
        'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-assets:' + dropwizardVersion,
        'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-forms:'+ dropwizardVersion,
        'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:' + httpComponentsVersion,

         ///Other Dependecies///  


     }

      task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = '3.3'
      }

      // Configure the shadow jar task
       shadowJar {
             mergeServiceFiles()
               exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
               exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
      }
      jar {
        zip64=true
          manifest {
                attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName
      }
       from {
            configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
      }

     }
```

.YAML file:

```
    server:
    rootPath: '/myrootpath/*'
    applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
    port: 8080
```

The same version is working in AWS srever, then Why it is not working in azure ?? How to resolve this issue??I have been working on this from two days but nothing is working out.Someone please help me out of this.

Comment: Your `YAML` file seems broken. `YAML` needs the `space` Indentation for each row to distinguish between elements and their subelements. See this question for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59880088/dropwizard-configurationparsingexception-when-running-through-the-command-line

Comment: Another possible problem could be the carriage return/line feed settings of the configuration file. If the Azure VM is a Windows-based check this also